# Disable automatic slideshow in Fancybox

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'am using fancybox jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.pack.js and want to disable the automatic slideshow when i used grouped_elements in my pages. Grouped photo's near each other works fine, but when i stack them i want no auto slideshow, how to do?
Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $("a[rel=group13]").fancybox({
          'autoPlay'      : false,
            'titleShow'     : false,            
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' +  (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + '</span>';
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<a name="Burstner Solano - T700 I"></a> 
<table width="990" cellpadding="22" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
   <th>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group13" href="/img/solano700/Image00.jpg"><img src="/img/solano700/Image00.jpg" width="400"></a> 
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group13" href="/img/solano700/Image01.jpg"><img src="/img/solano700/thumbs/Image01.jpg" width="50" height="33"></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group13" href="/img/solano700/Image04.jpg"><img src="/img/solano700/thumbs/Image04.jpg" width="50" height="33"></a>        
  </th>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();
</script>

</table>
```

Comment: Not totally sure what you are asking. At this point `$("a[rel=group13]").fancybox()` and `$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox()` do (almost) exactly the same (but the API options) and both launch a fancybox gallery. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JFK  i want disable the slideshow when i triggered the first picture, so the next picture can only be showed with the keybord arrow or mouse. Normally the next slide appears after a few seconds. In the above script and jquery-fancybox.js i tried to disable the slideshow but i can not find the right syntax. See for a example on the site I'm working at: http://www.camper-plus.nl/De%20Campers

Comment: The "automatic" slideshow that you see is NOT the default behavior of fancybox but a custom initialization, You need to find this line of code `setInterval($.fancybox.next, 15000);` and remove it.

Comment: @JFK, in first instance i did not remove all the code you mentioned, only at the beginning of some scripts at the page, i thought it would not have any consequence on the rest of the code. I was wrong about it and should remove all of it. Thanks for solving my problem Francisco!